# Lost OpenGL output

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

A week ago I upgraded my OS to the latest version, so GLEW, nVidia drivers, g++, Qt, etc. all got upgraded too.  That was the day my `QGLWidget`s stopped showing raw OpenGL 3.3 content, only the 2D `QPainter` based stuff.  Since no other OpenGL applications (including my DE) on my machine were affected, I must have written some dodgy code in my application, that perhaps had been allowed by older versions of these libraries - which have now been amended.

I have a lot of heavily abstracted OpenGL code, so many potential places for a failure; and after a few days of trying to get any sort of output from it (`glGetError()` was not returning errors before I started messing with it), I decided the best thing to do was write the simplest OpenGL application possible and then slowly build it up until it broke.

But I can't even get a triangle to appear!

```
void Viewer::initializeGL()
{
    //  Initialise GLEW, compile/link fragment and vertex shaders, error check, etc.
    ...

    //  Create default VAO.
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao_ );
    glBindVertexArray( vao_ );

    glUseProgram( shader_ );
    vVertex_ = glGetAttribLocation( shader_, "vVertex" );

    //  Create the test triangle VBO.
    glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo_ );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_ );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vVertex_ );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vVertex_, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
                           reinterpret_cast< GLvoid* >( 0 ) );

    //  Upload the data to the GPU.
    static const float verts[9] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f,
                                    1.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f,
                                    0.5f, 1.0f, -0.5f };
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( verts ),
                  static_cast< const void* >( verts ), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_NONE );
    glDisableVertexAttribArray( vVertex_ );
    Sy_GL::checkError();
}

void Viewer::paintGL()
{
    //  Clear the buffers.
    qglClearColor( QColor( Qt::black ) );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_ );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( vVertex_ );
    glVertexAttribPointer( vVertex_, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
                           reinterpret_cast< GLvoid* >( 0 ) );


    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_NONE );
    glDisableVertexAttribArray( vVertex_ );

    Sy_GL::checkError();
}
```

I'm not using my VAO for what it is for because VAOs cannot be shared across contexts, which is the scenario in my 'real' application, so I'm replicating that situation here.  `Sy_GL::checkError()` just calls `glGetError()` and throws an exception if there's a problem.  My two shaders could not be simpler:

```
//  Vertex shader.
#version 330
in vec3 vVertex;
void main( void )
{
    gl_Position = vec4( vVertex, 1.0 );
}

//  Fragment shader (in different file).
#version 330
out vec4 fragColour;
void main( void )
{
    fragColour = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

This should display a red line rendered triangle against a black background, but I just get the black background - no console output or exceptions.  My system really does support OpenGL 3.3 and higher, here is top of my  `glxinfo` output:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
```

And my `glewinfo` output:

```
GLEW version 1.9.0
Reporting capabilities of display :0, visual 0x2b
Running on a GeForce GTX 560 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 from NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL version 4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.32 is supported
```

So my question is:  Is my code wrong?  Or is my system damaged very subtly?

### Edit

It appears that `QGLFormat` is reporting that I only have **OpenGL v1.0** - what mechanism is Qt using to get that value?

In my 'real' application I perform a OpenGL version check using `QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags() & QGLFormat::OpenGL_Version_3_3`, and this passes; but using `myQGLWidget->format().majorVersion()` and `myQGLWidget->format().minorVersion()` return `1` and `0` respectively.

### Edit 2

Interestingly, if I set a default `QGLFormat` of v3.3 in my main.cpp:

```
QGLFormat format( QGL::DoubleBuffer |
                  QGL::DepthBuffer |
                  QGL::AlphaChannel );
format.setVersion( 3, 3 );
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat( format );
```

It segfaults on the first of *my* OpenGL calls, specifically `glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_)`, but `myQGLWidget->format().majorVersion()` and `myQGLWidget->format().minorVersion()` return `3` and `3` respectively.

Comment: When you call QGLWidget::format()::majorVersion() what does it report?

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar Hmm, it says it's reporting v1.0 - which is both wrong _and_ bad.  I'll update my question to include this.

Comment: To me it sounds like the OpenGL driver wasn't installed correctly. Which OS and what driver installation procedure did you follow? In the case of Windows Vista and later you **must** download the driver from the NVidia website. The drivers Windows installs automatically are crippled.

Comment: @datenwolf I'm running openSUSE 12.3 with the proprietary 310.32 nVidia drivers.  There's been reports of issues with those drivers and the 3.7.10 kernel, but it's odd how only my Qt app is having difficulty.  Although I use v3.3 features in my app, whilst the DE will probably just be using OpenGL ES 2.0 so that part of the driver may be OK.

Comment: @cmannett85: Some Linux distributions are doing strange things with the libGL.so. You should make sure that your program actually finds the libGL.so shipping with the NVidia drivers. It may fall back into Mesa's libGL.so otherwise. IMHO the only distribution to get the libGL.so issues right is Gentoo's eselect method; Debian's "alternatives" system also works, but IMHO not as reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently had this at work. The cause was the latest NVIDIA drivers, which broke the major and minor version queries.

**Edit:** I think it may have been related to calling these functions before setting up a valid GL context.
**End edit**

So, you could try with a slightly older driver. However, there is also an issue with some Qt versions and glversion. Check this link out:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20424

Comment: I'm running Qt v4.8, and I think you may be right.  There is a newer version of the nVidia out, so I'll try that first.

Comment: I tried one of the approaches in the forum link you posted, of forcing the `QGLFormat` to a particular OpenGL version, and setting that as the `QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(..)`.  But it triggers a segfault on the first of _my_ OpenGL calls.  Bizarre.

Comment: @cmannett85 Not so bizarre. could just be that context creation fails and the first of your calls leads to a dereference of nullptr if no context exists

Comment: I upgraded my kernel and nVidia driver versions and the problem vanished.  So thank you!